# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline - Unable to deploy .NET Core app

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

I'm trying to create a CI/CT pipeline for my project. All the steps got completed successfully including `Publish Build Artifacts` but unfortunately I get an error during azure webapp deployment

Build Pipeline
[image]

## Azure publish Step

[image]

## Publish Artifact: Drop

[image]

## Azure App Service Deploy: XXXX Server

[image]

I get following error in this step

> Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\a\Drop\xxx.xx.UI.API.zip

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the "Drop" from the Package or folder path in the Azure App Service Deploy task.

Comment: This solution worked.

Comment: Great :) I added it also as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "Drop" from the "Package or folder" path in the Azure App Service Deploy task.

Answer (score 0):

Create a release pipeline and use the Azure App Service Deploy task from there.

Comment: I can't create a release pipeline because my requirement is to trigger e2e tests post-deployment.